# Removing from list in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I need help with string concatenation on F#.

Given an integer n and list l, i have to remove all occurrences of n in l. For example:

```
 remove 1 (L(1, L(2, L(3, E)))) should give me L(2, L(3, E))
```

my code:

```
type ilist = E | L of int * ilist


let rec remove n l =
match l with
| E -> []
| L(h,E) -> if (h=n) then remove h (L(h,E))
            else [h, E]
| L(h,t) -> if (h=n) then remove h t
            else [h :: (remove n t)]
```

I am getting a type error saying that the last line expected to have type
    int * ilist
but here has type
    'a list

any help would be appreciated! thank you

Comment: list concatenation*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is a common one. You're wrapping the result in `[]`, forgetting that `h :: remove n t` is already a list. So my fixed version:

```
let rec remove n l =
  match l with
    | E -> []
    | L(h,t) -> if (h = n) then remove n t
                           else h :: (remove n t)
```

Note that you can get rid of your middle case, because it can be neatly solved by matching `t` with `E`.

I've also changed your `remove h` to `remove n`; even though they were guaranteed to be equal, I think it shows better that `n` 
is a "constant" parameter to the recursive function.